# how to get mysql command line client not to print blob fields in select *

Tags: mysql, blob

Exploring some tables which have blob fields. How could I do a `select *` with the command line client and have it surpress the printing (or truncate to a standard field width) the blob fields rather than scrolling a bunch of binary junk on the screen?  This is with mysql 5.1 client.  Just want to do a select * and not list all of the non-blob fields individually, for development.

Comment: Look into this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql Not exactly what you're looking for, but it allows to exclude specific columns, and automatic exclusion of BLOB fields may even be possible using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Comment: Thanks. None of those are really on target but I suppose I could write a stored procedure that uses the meta data to dynamically generate the query and ignore or truncate teh blogs. Seems like the statement syntax would need to be extended to SELECT * EXCEPT blob_column from table  etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be performed natively in MySQL, but it's quite unwieldy:

```
SET @sql=CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test' AND TABLE_NAME='test' 
    AND DATA_TYPE!='blob'), ' FROM test.test');
PREPARE preparedsql FROM @sql;
EXECUTE preparedsql;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE preparedsql;
```

I generally prefer BASH aliases/function to MySQL procedures as they're more transportable between systems:

```
function blobless()
{
  cols=''
  _ifs=$IFS
  IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
  for col in $(mysql --skip-column-names -e "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM 
      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='$1' AND TABLE_NAME='$2' 
      AND DATA_TYPE NOT LIKE '%blob'"); do 
    cols="$cols,$col"
  done
  IFS=$_ifs
  mysql -e "SELECT $(echo $cols | cut -c2-) FROM $1.$2 $3"
}
```

Invoke like so:

```
[andy ~]# blobless test test "where id>0"
+----+--------+
| id | t      |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 123    |
|  2 | 124213 |
+----+--------+
```

If you are in the MySQL client console use `Ctrl-Z` to suspend the program and drop to the shell. Then use `blobless db table` to check that blobless data. `fg` will restore the suspended job (i.e. MySQL client) to the foreground.

You can set default MySQL connection details in `~/.my.cnf` ([howto](http://support.modwest.com/content/6/242/en/how-do-i-create-a-mycnf-mysql-preference-file.html)) to save you having to supply host/user/pass on the command line - this will also be used by BASH functions.

Comment: Cool query construct in the first, but I too have similarly handled as your "blobless()" solution also provides