# Select Statement For my Question

Tags: mysql

I have 10 fields in my table but i need 8 fields when i select , i dont want to specify `select 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 from........` ,
Any easy way to get the 8 fields (Other hand i dont want to select primary,unique key fields)

Answer (score 1):

see the answer in this  :

[Select all columns except one in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

Actually there is a way, you need to have permissions of course for doing this ...

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), '<columns_to_delete>,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table>' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database>'), ' FROM <table>');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Replacing `<table>, <database> and <columns_to_delete>`