# How to insert data from an EXECUTE statement in mySql?

Tags: mysql, select, insert, prepared-statement

I have data in a `wp_users` table, and I want to duplicate the data from that table (except for the ID column) into another table, called `wp_users2`.

If I didn't care about the `id` column, which I want to auto-increment, I could just do this:

```
insert into wp_users2 (select *, NULL as ID from wp_users)
```

So I know I could do this by typing out all of the column headers except for ID and manually selecting that one as NULL,

```
SELECT NULL as id, col2, col3...
```

but I'd like to do it dynamically. I read [this great S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql) about how to do that, and it works, **however I can't figure out how to take the data it gives me and put it into an insert statement.**

```
INSERT INTO wp_users2 (
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT NULL as ID,', 
     (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'ID,', '') 
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
       WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'wp_users' 
       AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'wp1'),
     ' FROM wp_users');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
)
```

**What's the right syntax for that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand - id is AUTO_INCREMENT field.

So, try to use this script as an example for your task -

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  column1 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  column2 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE table2(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  column1 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  column2 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES 
  (1, 'c1', 'c2'),
  (2, 'c3', 'c4');

SET @source_table = 'table1';
SET @target_table = 'table2';
SET @id = 'id';

SET @columns = NULL;
SELECT group_concat(column_name) INTO @columns FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE
  table_schema = 'database_name' -- Set your database name here
  AND table_name = @source_table
  AND column_name != @id;

SET @insert = concat('INSERT INTO ', @target_table, '(', @id, ',', @columns, ') SELECT NULL, ', @columns, ' FROM ', @source_table);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @insert;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set @sql =  (select concat('insert into wp_users2 SELECT NULL,',
             group_concat(column_name),' from ',table_name) from information_schema.columns
         where table_name = 'wp_users' and table_schema = 'wp1' and column_name != 'id'
             order by ordinal_position);

prepare stmt1 from @sql;
execute stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
```