# Select all fields other than those listed?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select all columns except one in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

Hello,

`SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table WHERE 1` this query will select `field1`, `field2`, `filed3`

How to selected all fields except `field1`? Of course, we can tell to selected field2 and field3, but I'm talking about situation when there are a lot of such fields.

Thank you.

Comment: If your table has more than 10 fields, then it's very likely it needs normalization.

Answer (score 2):

You can't define a dynamic list in a `SELECT` clause, other than by using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
set @qry = (select concat('select ',group_concat(column_name), ' from ' ,table_name) from
information_schema.columns
where table_schema = database()
and table_name = 'your_table'
and column_name <> 'field_you_want_to_exclude');

prepare stmt from @qry;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use information_schema.columns to generate a select query that includes all columns other than those you want to ignore, then execute the sql generated dynamically.