# MySQL SELECT only 1 field with AS alias

Tags: mysql, sql, select, alias

I'd like to select all columns in a table, but give only one of them an alias.

I have this table:

```
id
base
window
thickness
shading
shape
... and many more columns
```

Now, I want to select the `base` with an alias, like so: `SELECT base AS structure`.
But I want to select all the other fields as well, without having to type them all out.

I tried `SELECT *, base AS structure`, but it gives me an error.

In truth, that's not even really what I want, because I don't want `base` to show up at all.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: FYI, never just say "it gives an error" without following that up with the actual error message

Comment: "it gives me an error" => I give you a stab in the face over the internet.

Comment: (FYI, selecting `*` and then again columns from the same table is not allowed.)

Answer (score 11):

No, it isn't. Suck it up and type them all out :)

Comment: Oh wow, 30? Well.. you don't have to do it all at once. Maybe type 10 columns, take a break, catch your breath, type 10 more, etc..

Comment: @Tom: LOL. Obviously, it is not your fault that I'm lazy, but that's not what I meant. It's not laziness. It's just that listing them all out like that is extremely prone to error. Let alone when the table is subsequently `altered`. I'm just baffled that they (MySQL) haven't thought of this to be of interest to anybody. I'm sure I'm not the only one with this problem!!

Comment: @John In that case, I'd recommend using an ORM. See [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/) (assuming PHP)

Comment: @John: Instead of assuming that the MySQL designers "haven't thought of this", you should instead jump to the (far more likely) conclusion that it is your requirement that is in error.

Comment: @Phil: I am. I'm using Codeigniter's Active Records class. But I don't see how that's gonna help me here...

Comment: @Tomalak: What do you mean by "your requirement is in error". How could I otherwise achieve this?

Comment: @John: Achieve _what_? What is your wider goal? Why do you feel that you need to alias this field?

Answer (score 4):

No.

You either list the ones you want, or you say "all" by writing `*`.

These are the two options at your disposal.

Laziness: begone! (And, let's face it, if you really need this alias, then your field is probably named wrong in the first place...)

---

Ultimately, you *could* create a `VIEW` to do this job transparently, but then you'd have to keep updating it as you `ALTER` your original table.

---

I was trying to avoid bringing this to your attention, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql/1495476#1495476) does demonstrate a rounadabout way:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), '<columns_to_exclude>,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table>' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database>'), ' FROM <table>');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

(Replacing `<table>`, `<database>` and `<columns_to_exclude>`).

I wish to re-iterate, though: don't. Something's wrong if you have to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind also having the old name you can do something like this:

SELECT MyTable.*, MyTable.base AS structure

Answer (score 2):

maybe there is a better way to solve your problem, at least the following answer works for you if you are not too lazy:

SELECT id, base AS structure, window, thickness, shading, shape ...  from yourTable

Comment: Which is precisely what I was trying to avoid!!

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know (and a check with the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) confirmed) that it's not possible to list all the column with the original name except one, at least using *.

Answer (score 1):

Inefficient, but clean, try left joining the same rows to themselves then selecting from the left join the desired column with its new name.

ie.

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.base AS structure 
SELECT 
    table_1.*, 
    table_2.base AS structure 
FROM 
    table1 AS table_1 
        LEFT JOIN table2 AS table_2 
            ON table_1.id=table_2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

`SELECT firstName AS firstStudent FROM student LIMIT 1;`