# MySQL create table with select, alias column names

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to use a create table with select statement where column names in conflict (or all) are aliased?

```
CREATE TABLE newTable
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM tblA a
JOIN tblB b
  ON a.id = b.cid
```

The issue is that tblA and tblB have a few columns with the same name, so I get a "duplicate column name" error on the create. I'm trying to avoid listing all the fields in the table, so I either need to selectively exclude some columns or apply and "auto alias" to the column names.

Comment: I think that you're going to have to list out the columns, and manually assign aliases...

Comment: It depends. Do you want values from both tables for columns with duplicate names? Or do you just want (for example) the MAX value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the information_schema table to selectively exclude columns in a select statement.  See the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql).