# Zend SQL Select ALL columns except one

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, select

My "Users" table has many many fields, including the password field. So, if I want to select a user and get ALL the information, how can I do this in Zend but excluding the password field? I know I can manually type in all the fields, but I was wondering if there is a way to exclude one field?

Thanks
Kousha

Comment: there are few suggestions in this post [Select all columns except one in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is an efficient way to do this (I believe the meta data can be cached), but you could use `Zend_Db_Table` to [get the columns](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.info), then just remove the password column.

Would look something like this:

```
$info = $table->info();
$columns = $info['cols'];
unset($columns[array_search('password', $columns)]);
//you can now pass $columns to a Zend_Db_Select
```