# Select every columns, but rename one of them

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's assume I have a table named  Alphabet. Now let's say this table has the following columns:

a, b, c, d, e ..., z

Now I want to select everything from the mentioned table (but select f as aaa), but I don't want to do this:

```
select a, b, c, d, e, f as aaa, g ..., z
from Alphabet;
```

Clearly the above is cumbersome if the are a lot of columns. So I am thinking if it is possible to do something like

```
select f as aaa, *
from Alphabet;
```

This is probably something there is a lot info about on the net, but I'm not sure what to search for. Has this kind of select got an expression or name?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can write this:

```
select a.f as aaa, a.*
from Alphabet a;
```

Note that the output set will contain both `f` and `aaa`.  It is unclear whether this is what you want.

To remove `f` from the result set, you need to list all the columns that you do want.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, it's that it still selects f, I might need it. Thanks.

Comment: awesome, very helpful

Comment: For my purpose, I can't have both.  The original must not be present because the output is being sent to a reporting tool and both columns will end up showing up.  I can't think of any solution other than to explicitly include every column name in the table in the select statement and using the "as" clause for the one I want to rename.