# How to replace date value in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, case, sql-view

I am using Oracle and trying to create a view in which I will replace one date value with another date value. I am trying to use `case when` statement, however, I need to use the same column name as an alias and I get the error that I have duplicate column names. Do you know how to fix it or propose the alternative for replacing date value in a column and creating view? I need to keep the original table unchanged.
Code:

```
create view name_of_view as
select t.*,
(case when birth_date = to_date('4.12.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
 then to_date('4.12.1950', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
 else birth_date end) as birth_date
 from table t;
```

Comment: t.* is an antipattern. Use full column list. Oracle does not support [SELECT * EXCEPT/REPLACE syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031225/rename-single-column-in-select-in-sql-select-all-but-a-column/52243902#52243902)

Comment: And is there another option in which using the full column list is not needed? My table has around 100 columns.

Comment: I don't insist on using case statement for replacing, I just need to create the view and do not change existing table.

Comment: `SELECT col1, col2, ...` You don't need to write it by hand. Just drag and drop from object explorer(if you are using SQL Developer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@Lukasz Szozda` has suggested in the comments, when you try `t.*` it will retrieve all columns from your table, including `birth_date`.
So when you add another `birth_date` as part of your `case when`, you receive the duplicate column name error.

What you need to do is:

- You either change the `case when` column name to something like: `birth_date_new` or whatever then you will have both of the columns.
- You retrieve all columns by their names and when retrieving `birth_date` you apply `case when`.

Comment: I need to keep the same column name: `birth_date` for the view, just change the value in it. So there is no other replace option than `case when` that woul allow me to replace it for the view?

Comment: For example, update the view somehow in the same fashion as update table works?

Comment: Without listing all the columns - I want to avoid a superlong query

Comment: In fact no, you either select (*) or you select specifics. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9133172/8943967

Or if it is a must, you can write a pl/sql block and do lots of queries to achieve what you want.

Comment: @doremi use as "Birth_Date" then to alias the case statement by keeping asterisk.