# select all but use newname for some fields while selecting all data

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use newname on selected fields while selecting all fields.

ie

```
SELECT id NEWNAME uid all fields form table;
```

is there anyway for me to do this, since the table has a lot of fields i was looking for a shorter version. or i could always get the fields of the table implode them in a string replace the field with field NEWNAME new_field but that is not short at all. so any suggestions?

thank you

Comment: You can do `SELECT *, id NEWNAME, othercol OTHERNAME` which will give you _duplicate_ columns, one of which has your `NEWNAME` alias, but it is always recommended to be explicit in the `SELECT` list anyway, and not `SELECT *` in production code.

Comment: Is the table not normalized?

Comment: so that will give me id and its newname? so can i just use exemption in the query to not include the oldnames?

Comment: what do you mean by normalized?

Comment: What do you mean by "use exemption"?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ Normalization doesn't seem to be relevant to this question. Unless you think the reason it has so many fields is because  normalization would move many columns into another table.

Comment: @Barmar I guess I'm not seeing the OP's reason for pulling the ID twice unless there were duplicate columns?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ He doesn't want to pull it twice, he wants to pull all fields but give this field an alias.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253994/selecting-all-fields-except-only-one-field-in-mysql - exemption but I dont think i can apply it there. I dont plan on pulling ID twice i want to rename id to  uid to meet a certain specification, and since the table is also used else where it should retain its current column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MySQL `SELECT` reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> A select_expr can be given an alias using AS *alias_name*. The **alias** is
>   used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY,
>   ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses. For example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(last_name,', ',first_name) AS full_name
FROM mytable ORDER BY full_name;
```

## In operation

To do this you need to use an alias and specifically call every table column that you would need to pull. But NOT use the `*` column match for all columns. An example might be:

```
SELECT id as user_id,name as user_name,
st_code as state,postal as zipcode from table
```

If you were pulling from two different tables by had duplicate column names you would do something like:

```
SELECT a.id as user_id,b.id as parent_id
from table_1 a,table_2 b where b.name=a.name;
```

Comment: from the recent comments this will also return both id and user_id, am i correct?

Comment: @magicianlam if you have two different columns, one id and one user_id they would only be returned if you requested them.

Comment: is it possible not to include id in the result query? as to avoid duplicate entries. thank you

Comment: You can include it as many times as you want. More than once and it might be confusing on the programming side.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage to select all `COLUMS` from a table simply using `*` and selecting id with an `ALIAS`

```
SELECT *, id as NEWNAME from table;
```

Comment: To as the OP called it *"exempt"* old names they would have to list every column with it's new name and not use the `*` column match for all columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

```
select a.id as newname, a.* from tablename a
```

while the disadvantage is id is repeated as well in the selected columns.

Comment: then can i just use an exemption to not include id?

Comment: You can't add any exempts there. a.* will include all fields. you will have an additional field which you can ignore while processing the result set. if you don't want any additional fields, there is no way except you explicitly specify what fields you want.

like select a.id, a.title, a.desc from tablename a

Comment: yes but then the id given a new name will also be called, so in my query i will now have id-"old" and id-"new". correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Yes, you will have both fields in your result set.

Comment: i also want to exclude the old id from the result