# How to dynamically create row and column of table in jsp page

Tags: html, database, jsp, select, html-table

I am trying to retrieve data from database into table.
But data must be loaded dynamically.

How to dynamically create row and column I don't know?
If it will be only row to create then I will do it easily but I also want to create column dynamically on page so that's why I am confused how to perform it?

My JSP code :

```
<table width="59%" border="1">
    <%
        MySql1 o = new MySql1();
        o.connect();
        ResultSet r;
        int counter=1;
        String q = "select * from category_master;";
        r = o.getdata(q);
        while(r.next())
        {
            %>
                <tr>
                     <td><%= r.getString(1)%></td>                                      
                </tr>
            <% 
        }
    %>
</table>
```

Right now I am displaying first column in `<td>` but if the user don't know how many columns are going to be retrieved then what to do ?
In `select query` I have used `*` so I am confused for taking `<td>`.
I want to all dynamic because suppose I will pass table name also dynamically using any textbox or url.

Here `MySql`1 is one class file that has method to perform operation.
`connect()` is used to connect with db, and `getdata()` is used to retrieve data of query passed as argument and return type of `getdata()` method is `Resultset`.

So that's why I want all dynamic, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this code:

```
<table width="59%" border="1">
    <%
        MySql1 o = new MySql1();
        o.connect();
        ResultSet r;
        int counter=1;
        String q = "select * from category_master;";
        r = o.getdata(q);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = r.getMetaData();
        while(r.next())
        {
            %>
                <tr>
                 <%
                 for(int i = 1; i<=metaData.getColumnCount();i++)
                    { %>
                     <td>
                     <%= r.getString(i)%>
                     </td>
                <% 
                    }
                %>                   
                </tr>
            <% 
        }
    %>
</table>
```

Comment: Sir is it possible that if i will write query to fetch all data using select * but i don't want one field. such thing possible or not ? suppose it is table of user detail and i don't want to display password except it i want all data.

Comment: look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253994/selecting-all-fields-except-only-one-field-in-mysql

Comment: Sir i am not getting it exactly what it means and i am beginner in this field so that's why i am facing problem. will you tell me how to perform it ?

Comment: Sir i have implemented 2 mechanism. In first i have fetched column name from table and display as header and after that in second i have fetched data from table name but it shows an error in ResultSetMetaData declaration in second implementation, if i pass table name directly not a variable fetched from other page then it shows an error in ResultSetMetaData delaration...

Comment: I have posted my question with code sir .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095898/error-shows-on-resultsetmetadata

Answer (score 0):

I did jsp page for testing like this

here it is `test.jsp`

```
<table width="59%" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Volume</td>
        <td>XmlTitle</td>
        <td>getYear</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%
        Journal journal = Journal.findByCode("antipoda");
        List<Issue> normalIssues = journal.getIssuesOfType(IssueType.NORMAL);
        for (Issue issue : normalIssues) {

            out.print(String.format("<tr>" +
                                        "<td>%s</td>" +
                                        "<td>%s</td>" +
                                        "<td>%d</td>" +
                                    "</tr>",
                    issue.getVolume(),issue.getXmlTitle(),issue.getYear()));
        }

        out.flush();
    %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

you can change the scriptlet to the code that iterates thru the model you want to display

hope this helps