# How to dynamically add table into my jsp page

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, jsp

I have to dynamically add table on pressing the add table button(on clicking a button) and have to change the table id so that the new table will have different id with different

```
<table id="dataTable">
   <tr>
      <td>FACILITY</td>
      <td><select id="select1" onchange="loadxml2()" ></select></td>
   </tr>
<table>
```

in the code above on clicking the add button(which i have not created) table should reappear 
with id select id select1 changed to select2.Can anyone help??.Got struck up with this for a long time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066966/how-to-dynamically-create-row-and-column-of-table-in-jsp-page

Comment: Use clone, check this example out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126395/how-to-jquery-clone-and-change-id