# How do we fetch data from the database except one fields in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do we fetch the data from the database except for one field in Codeigniter
Table name employees
the exceptional field is employee_resign_date

Basically I don't need to show the employe in salary section once employee resigned

Comment: Provide more info with database

Comment: there is `select()` and its very common, you can find from document of CI .

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in few ways.

1. Put required fields only in select statement.

   Assume that excepted field is 'field2' then like below.
   select ('field1', 'field3', 'field4')
2. This way also you can try to do.
   [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14255012)
3. Here another way of doing.
   [Thy this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1495476)