# how to select the rest of the table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, subquery

Suppose you have 2 tables.
Book(TITLE)
and
Subject(IDSUBJECT, title)
where title in subject references to title in book.
What's the query to find all the books that are not liked to a subject?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253994/selecting-all-fields-except-only-one-field-in-mysql/14254068

Comment: Note that it would be unlikely to relate  tables in this way; it's possible for two books to have the same title.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select b.*
from books b
where not exists (select 1 from subject s where s.title = b.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT 
     book.TITLE
FROM 
     Book AS book

LEFT JOIN Subject AS subj 

ON book.TITLE = subj.TITLE

WHERE 
subj.IDSUBJECT IS NULL;
```

Comment: Why do you add this answer two years late? And this anti join syntax is considered less readable than a mere `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`. clause. Why do you suggest using this over the already given answer? And then, please don't write code-only answers. Explain what the query does and how it solves the problem.