# MySQL query all fields except

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if there is a query to check all fields in a table without enumerating all the fields.  My pseudo code would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE * > 5 except table.id;
```

Is there such query?

Comment: seems like `Select Top(5) where != id`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql ?

Comment: Not. You have to enumerate all needed fields or use '*' to get all fields. Or generate SQL statement dynamic.

Comment: When following the link provided by Zubin, make sure to read Jan Koritak's answer, not only the accepted one.