# MySQL table export without one field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP, and I do not it's syntax and principles very well.
I have such code:

```
 function exportFromTransbase($table_name) {
 //$odbc_query = "SELECT * FROM " . $table_name. " WHERE ((CDS_CTM subrange(248 cast integer) = 1) AND (CDS_LNG_ID = 16))";
 $odbc_query = "SELECT * FROM " . $table_name. "";

 $data = odbc_exec($this->odbc_id, $odbc_query);
 odbc_longreadlen($data, 10485760);
 $oufile=fopen($table_name.".sql", 'w') or die("error writing file");

    $q1='INSERT INTO `' . substr($table_name, 4) . '` VALUES';
    fwrite($oufile, $q1);

 while($row = odbc_fetch_array($data))
 {

 foreach($row as $key => $value) {
 $keys[] = "`" . $key . "`";
 if ($value == ""){
    $value = 'NULL';
 $values[] = "" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "";
 }
 else{
    $values[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
 }
 //echo "\n \n ololo  ".$value;

 }


 $mysql_query = "\n (".implode(",", $values).")," ;
fwrite($oufile, $mysql_query);
 //mysql_query($mysql_query);
 set_time_limit(0);
 unset($keys);
 unset($values);
 unset($row);
 }
 $stat = fstat($oufile);
ftruncate($oufile, $stat['size']-1);
fseek($oufile, 0, SEEK_END);
  fwrite($oufile, ";".$r);
//} while ($r < 5 );
fclose($oufile);
    if ($mysql_query){
        print "Ýêñïîðò äàííûõ èç òàáëèöû " . $table_name . " çàâåðøåí!";
        //strtolower(substr($table_name, 4))
    }
 }
```

*what and where i need to custom, so that i export all table fields except one, for example called Size, i must insert in db is this field nulls....*

Also if it is easy, how to split my sql query in batches of 5000 rows? so insert (5000 rows) then insert another 5000....

But first i need to export all fields, except one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it can't be possible.

You can use simply:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM table
```

See [Select all columns except one in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

And if you have more fields in your `table` then you can use `*` only.

At the time of `insert` you can make a `condition` which `ignores` the `field` which you don't want in `new table`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you use

```
"select * from {table} where {sth} != {condition}"
```

Then you can fetch all data except one. The one is excrpted follow your condition.
Meanwhile,if you want to insert by 5000, you can read 5000 lines one time and insert into.