# Mysql not select columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table contain 22 columns

I have a query need to `SELECT` 20 columns

Is any way to do a query like **NOT SELECT (the columns i don't want to select)**

So I don't need to type `SELECT column1, columns2...`

Comment: You can hide the fields in a view so you don't need to complicate your query by selecting 20 out of 22 columns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible, the expression `"select all except"` or `"NOT SELECT"` has not yet been implemented in any existing database.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it as you expected. You have to type all the columns you want. If you have run the query many times, you can create a VIEW with selected columns.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to specify the columns you want or use the '*' wildcard

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

or

```
SELECT column1, column2...
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL doesn't allow to hide some columns. You can either select all columns by using `SELECT * ...` or list columns you need by `SELECT col1, col2, ...`

Answer (score 1):

Please check this answer. It is the only way to do that

[Select all columns except one in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

(I can't comment so I put the link as an answer)

Cheers