# CREATE TABLE as SELECT - using MEMORY ENGINE (in RAM memory)

Tags: mysql

I was reading about tables using [`MEMORY ENGINE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html) (tables stored in ram).

- Is it possible to use `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` syntax, but have the created table us `MEMORY ENGINE`?
- Is there a limit to the size of a MEMORY table? Could create a MEMORY table that is a copy of a pysical 1.5 GB table?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- Yes, it can be done, but not with simple syntax `CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT ...` - you will need to specify table columns in [full statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html), Sample:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE t (col1 INT(11), col2 INT(11)) 
  ENGINE=MEMORY 
  AS 
  SELECT * FROM another_t
  ```
- Maximum size of table by default if `16Mb`, but it can be adjusted with [`max_heap_table_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) server system variable. But please, note, that this limit is *per engine* - not *per table*. I.e. all your `memory` tables will share it. To restrict size of individual table, you'll need to operate on *session* value for `max_heap_table_size`, like

  ```
   mysql> SET max_heap_table_size = 24*1024*1024;
  ```

Comment: +1. Also I remember reading that if the `max_heap_table` is reached the table is silently written to disk.

Comment: "The actual limit is determined from whichever of the values of `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` is smaller. If an in-memory temporary table exceeds the limit, MySQL automatically converts it to an on-disk MyISAM table. Increase the value of `tmp_table_size` (and `max_heap_table_size` if necessary) if you do many advanced `GROUP BY` queries and you have lots of memory."
Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size

Comment: @Bad_Neighbor this is true but only for internal temporary memory tables. Alma Do gives example about a non-temporary memory table, which is also what the OP asks about.

Answer (score 12):

you can also create a temporary table this way:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp ENGINE=MEMORY AS (
SELECT 'abc' As tomcat, 'def' As apache);
```

Or this way:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp ENGINE=MEMORY AS (
SELECT tomcat, apache From servers);
```

Be advised, the first option will create the two columns as varchar(3), meanwhile the second option will import any column information from the original table, even their comments.