# MySQL Specify Temp Table Engine When Using AS

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

Is it possible to specify the Engine when using CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE xxx **AS** (SELECT ...) ?
I tried but this fails:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test AS (
SELECT myCol
FROM myTable
) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

I've searched for an example of this but to no avail, using **AS**. :(

Comment: Hi. How was this not answered by googling the manual?

Comment: As per the comments below (Addy and Paul), the issue turned out to be that cols MUST be specified IF using the memory engine (but not otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with simple syntax `CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT` ... - you will need to specify table columns in full statement, Sample:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (myCol varchar(100)) 
ENGINE=MEMORY 
AS 
SELECT myCol FROM myTable;
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144394/create-table-as-select-using-memory-engine-in-ram-memory)

Comment: "This is possible with simple syntax ..." - I think you mean "This is **not** possible with simple syntax ...". Also note: "MEMORY tables use a fixed-length row-storage format. Variable-length types such as VARCHAR are stored using a fixed length". That means that `varchar(100)` using `utf8` is a fixed 300 bytes column.

Comment: Thanks Addy and Paul. I see the issue with *AS*  is that it requires the columns to be specified when using the MEMORY engine.