# Search recursively in MySQL5.7 table

Tags: java, mysql

I have a `parameters` table as shown below:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| param0 | 1 + $(param1) |
| param1 | 1 + $(param2) + $(param3) |
| param2 | 1 + $(param4) |
| param4 | 1 + 3 |
| param3 | 1 + 2 |

I trying to write a query to get the list of parameters used in `param0`.

Expected output is:

| id |
| --- |
| param1 |
| param2 |
| param3 |
| param4 |

**Explanation:**

`param0` contains `param1` so need to search in `param1`

`param1` contains `param2` and `param3` so need to search in `param2`, `param3`

`param2` contains `param4` so need to search in `param4`

`param3` and `param4` doesn't contains any parameters so search will stop here.

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dqYPjVfjzuLrQ3vQCpTEpc/0)

Comment: Version 5.7 cannot perform this in a query. Iterative stored procedure needed.

Comment: You should start thinking about upgrading to MySQL 8.0, since 5.7 will be end-of-life by October 2023.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_params_list (param VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE params_list (param VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
                          param_value VARCHAR(255)) ENGINE = Memory;
INSERT INTO params_list 
SELECT *
FROM parameters
WHERE parameters.param = param;
REPEAT
    INSERT IGNORE INTO params_list
    SELECT parameters.*
    FROM params_list
    JOIN parameters ON LOCATE(CONCAT('$(', parameters.param, ')'),
                              params_list.param_value);
UNTIL NOT ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;
SELECT params_list.param 
FROM params_list
WHERE params_list.param <> param;
DROP TABLE params_list;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2f51944e354f92cfe7d428ce84f46184

Comment: PS. I use asterisks - but I strongly recommend to replace them with definite columns names lists. While replacing, the table alias in INSERT is compulsory!

Answer (score 0):

Without a stored procedure, and with a maximum level of 3:

```
SET @search = 'param';

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Ptemp
   SELECT PARAM, P
   FROM (
      SELECT 
         PARAM,
         PARAM_VALUE,
         x.x,
         substring_index(substring_index(replace(PARAM_VALUE,')','('),'(',x.x),'(',-1) as P
      FROM parameters 
      CROSS JOIN (select 1 as x union
            select 2 as x union
            select 3 as x union
            select 4 as x ) x 
     ) x 
   WHERE P LIKE 'param%' 
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Ptemp1 as SELECT * FROM Ptemp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Ptemp2 as SELECT * FROM Ptemp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Ptemp3 as SELECT * FROM Ptemp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Ptemp4 as SELECT * FROM Ptemp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Ptemp5 as SELECT * FROM Ptemp;

select P from Ptemp WHERE PARAM=@search
union all
select P from Ptemp1 WHERE PARAM IN (select P 
                                     from Ptemp2 
                                     WHERE PARAM=@search)
union all
select P from Ptemp3 WHERE PARAM IN (select P 
                                     from Ptemp4 
                                     WHERE PARAM IN (select P 
                                                     from Ptemp5 
                                                     WHERE PARAM=@search))
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=53496e3907c08c3b25e7d0a78d7abbb2)

or [DB-FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dqYPjVfjzuLrQ3vQCpTEpc/0)

The (multiple) copies of the temp table are needed because MySQL will give this error when re-using a temp table:

> Query Error: Error: ER_CANT_REOPEN_TABLE: Can't reopen table: 'Ptemp1'

Conclusion: Writing a stored procedure is the way to go, at least in MySQL before version 8.0.

Comment: I think that one static table is better than a lot of copies of temptable (each temptable copy will be saved on disk!). `ENGINE=Memory` is more suitable if the table size is not too huge, and it may provide great improvement.

Comment: When doing `ENGINE=MEMORY` the error is not solved, see: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dqYPjVfjzuLrQ3vQCpTEpc/0

Comment: You provide incorrect link, it seems. Anycase, ENGINE=Memory must be used instead of TEMPORARY, not in addition to - in this case only table definition and not table data is saved to disk.

Comment: oops, link should be: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dqYPjVfjzuLrQ3vQCpTEpc/2

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dqYPjVfjzuLrQ3vQCpTEpc/3 - TEMPORARY is commented.

Comment: see: [Is there a limit ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20144674/724039), and a non-temporary memory table will ramin, even after a server reboot. So you need to make sure it's empty before doing something with it, because others can access it too, so (in my opinion) TEMPORARY is needed, which makes sure the table is removed at the end of the session.