# how to concat two columns into one with the existing column name in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to concatenate two columns in a table with a existing column name using mysql.

An example: I am having a column `FIRSTNAME` and `LASTNAME` and so many columns also. I want to concatenate these two columns with the name of `FIRSTNAME` only.

So I tried like this:

```
 SELECT *, CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ',', LASTNAME) AS FIRSTNAME FROM `customer`;
```

but it displaying the two fields with the name of `FIRSTNAME`. one field is having normal values and another one is having concatenated values. I want only one column with those concatenate value. I can select single columns, but am having more than 40 columns in my table.

Is there any way to remove the original column using mysql itself?

Comment: See this question for relevant info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql

Answer (score 142, accepted):

As  aziz-shaikh has pointed out, there is no way to suppress an individual column from the `*` directive, however you might be able to use the following hack:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.FIRSTNAME, ',', c.LASTNAME) AS FIRSTNAME,
       c.*
FROM   `customer` c;
```

Doing this will cause the second occurrence of the `FIRSTNAME` column to adopt the alias `FIRSTNAME_1` so you should be able to safely address your customised `FIRSTNAME` column. You need to alias the table because `*` in any position other than at the start will fail if not aliased.

Comment: so the PHP coding will take the first column only in this case? right?

Comment: If you are referencing "FIRSTNAME" in your PHP script, then your version of the column will be used because the real "FIRSTNAME" will now be called "FIRSTNAME_1".

What makes it work is not really the fact that it's the first column, but that it uses the same alias as the original column *and* it's listed *before* the original column. That way it forces out the original column into a different name.

Comment: @Raad , @starball -  In my case I'm having my SQL table name itself has a period (.) within it i.e., customer.table. With this scenario, I'm not able to execute the query - 

Bcoz, FROM `customer.table` is not being accepted!!  could you please suggest your views ? apart from changing the name of the db table (which I can't do so)

Comment: @Giri - I have not tested this, but if you are using MySQL try enclosing the table name in backticks (i.e. the quoted identifiers) It should then treat the period as part of the table name.

Answer (score 26):

Instead of getting all the table columns using * in your sql statement, you use to specify the table columns you need.

You can use the SQL statement something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' ', LASTNAME) AS FIRSTNAME FROM customer;
```

BTW, why couldn't you use FullName instead of FirstName? Like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' ', LASTNAME) AS 'CUSTOMER NAME' FROM customer;
```

Answer (score 15):

You can try this simple way for combining columns:

```
select some_other_column,first_name || ' ' || last_name AS First_name from customer;
```

Comment: This works on Oracle and Postgres. On MySQL you'll need to: SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `*` from your query and use individual column names, like this:

```
SELECT SOME_OTHER_COLUMN, CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ',', LASTNAME) AS FIRSTNAME FROM `customer`;
```

Using `*` means, in your results you want all the columns of the table. In your case `*` will also include `FIRSTNAME`. You are then concatenating some columns and using alias of `FIRSTNAME`. This creates 2 columns with same name.

Comment: but am having nearly 43 columns, Is this is a only way? I have to mention other 42 columns in query like this "select col1,col2,col3,..etc" ?

Comment: In this case, as mentioned by @oGeez above, you can try the answers given at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove * from your select clause, and mention all column names explicitly and omit the FIRSTNAME column. After this write CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ',', LASTNAME) AS FIRSTNAME.
The above query will give you the only one FIRSTNAME column.

Answer (score -2):

I am a novice and I did it this way:

```
Create table Name1
(
F_Name varchar(20),
L_Name varchar(20),
Age INTEGER
)

Insert into Name1
Values
('Tom', 'Bombadil', 32),
('Danny', 'Fartman', 43),
('Stephine', 'Belchlord', 33),
('Corry', 'Smallpants', 95)
Go

Update Name1
Set F_Name = CONCAT(F_Name, ' ', L_Name)
Go

Alter Table Name1
Drop column L_Name
Go

Update Table_Name
Set F_Name
```

Comment: You could also include some explanation as to what you did in your code, to make it easier to understand at a glance.