# Returning result from two functions within a function - how?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have two functions, qdgc_getlonlat and qdgc_getrecursivestring, which separately return a string. I am now creating a new function where the goal is concatenate the results from the said functions. This is where I am now:

```
return query 
  select * 
  from qdgc_getlonlat(lon_value,lat_value) 
  union distinct 
  select * 
  from qdgc_getrecursivestring(lon_value,lat_value,depthlevel,'');
```

Unfortunately it returns an array which look slike this:

[image]

Not too bad, but I would like the functions to be returned as a concatenated text string like this:

> E007S05BDCA

How can I do this?

Comment: `union` will add rows. IF you can manage to get two columsn, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26792631/1897935

Comment: @SrinathGanesh thanks, but calling two functions seem to mess it up. Considered calling them separately and then concatenating with string handling. But I can not see how it should be done. I should mention that I am not a professional programmer.

Comment: Does @S-Man solution solve it? it looks right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply concatenate them?

```
SELECT
    qdgc_getlonlat(lon_value,lat_value)  || qdgc_getrecursivestring(lon_value,lat_value,depthlevel,'')
FROM
    mytable
```