# MySQL event variables - copy value to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
    DO
      BEGIN
        DELETE FROM vehicle WHERE last_updated < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
      END |

DELIMITER ;
```

Above I have a MySQL event that runs every minute deleting rows that haven't been updated for 5 minutes. I have another table called saved_vehicles. All of the rows in `vehicle` will have a row in the `saved_vehicle` table. What I want to do is essentially copy over the `last_updated` time to the `saved_vehicle` table (for example purposes, imagine the `saved_vehicle` field would be `last_known_online_time`. This essentially saves a copy of the vehicle with its last known online time.

Essentially I'm creating a backup before deleting the row.

Answer (score 0):

Insert into saved_vehicles before delete.
Try this:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
    DO
      BEGIN
        SET @time = NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;

            # select * is not very smart, it will also copy your primary key, 
            # so you can get error about duplicates. Listing fields would work here.
        INSERT INTO saved_vehicle (SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE last_updated < @time); 
        DELETE FROM vehicle WHERE last_updated < @time;

      END |

DELIMITER ;
```

To avoid listing fields i've mentioned in comment try to select all fields except your primary key column.
To do this check [how to select all columns except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

**update**
I through about insert i mentioned above - and if your `saved_vehicle` table has same structure as `vehicle` table, but its primary key has different name than `vehicle` (f.e. `base_id`, when `vehicle` PK is `id`) and its `int auto_increment` then it will work nice as it is.