# Select Data MySQL Without Show Primary Key And Unique Field

Tags: mysql

I have table like this.

```
id_people | name
1            John
4            Jenny
7            Nik
```

results i want.

```
no     |  name
1         John
2         Jenny
3         Nik
```

I want to running query to select data from my table with statement everything (*) without show Primary key and unique field and without having to call all name of field. Can i do that ?

Comment: Can you present it with sample data and resultset.

Comment: Just select the field which you want to query. Ex. Select id, table1, table from people;

Comment: Ok. i've revision my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT  @a:=@a+1 no, p.* FROM people p,(SELECT @a:= 0) AS a;
```

Comment: Thanks @Manu. But i mean, Can i create query mysql with statement * (everything) without showing Primary key and unique field ?

Comment: yes you can achieve this. For better and v.good explanation check the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql