# column is ambiguous using information_schema

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this code below:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.name AS size,', 
    (SELECT REPLACE(
        GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 
        'ps.product_id, ps.status, ps.created_by, ps.created_at, ps.updated_at, ps.deleted_at,', ''
    ) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'product_sku' 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'swafap'), ' FROM product_sku AS ps
INNER JOIN size_code AS s ON s.id = ps.size_code_id
WHERE ps.product_id = 4741');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

I have a lot of columns I need to select from product_sku. I looked at the popular answer post to figure this out. I selected other columns and stuff with no problem, but as soon as I do a join, it says id is ambiguous which makes sense because id exists in both tables..

However, I'm not really sure on how to fix this properly since I'm still trying to wrap my head around what it's doing right here.

In product_sku, is has a column called 'size_code_id' which I only need to reference the name of that size code in the size_code table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope I can translate this into Laravel using fluent/eloquent =) Because I really like this solution. My original query looks like this:

```
SELECT ps.manufacturer_sku, ps.sku, ps.units, s.name AS size, ps.smis, ps.purchase_cost, ps.branch_cost,
ps.annual_sales_unit, ps.annual_sales_dollar, ps.pipeline_unit, ps.pipeline_dollar, ps.upc_barcode, ps.lvl_1_scc_barcode,
ps.mast_carton_scc_barcode, ps.pallet_scc_barcode, ps.prod_manufacturer_comp, ps.part_no_comp, ps.wd_price_comp,
ps.jobber_price_comp, ps.refinisher_price_comp, ps.retail_price_comp, ps.initial_lead_time, ps.reorder_lead_time, 
ps.min_quant, ps.manufacturer_location, ps.country_code, ps.tariff_code, ps.weight, ps.lngth, ps.height, ps.width,
ps.shipping_desc, ps.lvl_1_quant, ps.master_carton_quant, ps.pallet_quant, ps.wd_price_rec, ps.jobber_price_rec, 
ps.refinisher_price_rec, ps.retail_price_rec
FROM product_sku AS ps
INNER JOIN size_code AS s ON s.id = ps.size_code_id
WHERE ps.product_id = 4741;
```

Very ugly..

Comment: Using your orignal query. With your long select statement and then instead of saying inner join, try "From product_sku as ps,size_code as s where ps.product_id=4741 and s.id=ps.size_code_id"

Comment: The second query works fine... But it's ugly and I was trying to switch to the first one I posted.

Comment: And that still says the ambiguous notification

Answer (score 1):

I don't claim to understand your string processing (`REPLACE` logic). But you would do well to qualify your column names with the table name as you use `information_schema` data to build up your query.

That is, perhaps

```
GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
```

should be

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(TABLE_NAME,'.','COLUMN_NAME))
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Z0auY95L Here you can see it after your changes. Now it's saying product_sku.re column doesn't exist.. I'm not sure how it's even getting that error? re? I'm not even calling that column.

This is the board that I'm getting the first query from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql