# Is it possible to select certain elements of the database table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For example: I have a table name tbl_admin and I have so many table elements within that table.

Like (id, fname, lname, contact_info, email, ip, date, status, etc.and so on upto 20 elements).

Now I need to exclude only 3 elements from that table as you can say (fname, lname and contact_info) and select all others. Is this possible by using the mysql query?

Please help me if this is possible. Thanks,

Comment: no its not possible you have to write all the fields which you want to select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl_admin");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $columns[] = $row['Field'];
    }
}
//fill all columns here that you want to exclude
$columns_to_exclude = array('fname','lname','contact_info'); 
$sql = "SELECT (";
foreach($columns as $ind=>$val){

    if(!in_array($val,$columns_to_exclude))
    {
        $sql .= $val.", ";
    }
}
$sql = rtrim($sql,", ");
$sql .= ") FROM tbl_admin;";

echo $sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**
You can't exclude columns *explicitly*, but you can do so *implicitly* by selecting only the other columns:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    EMAIL,
    IP,
    DATE,
    STATUS
FROM tbl_admin
```

**Long Answer**
It turns out I was wrong with the short answer, technically there is a way as illustrated with the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql?lq=1).

To do this in PHP, I'd recommend creating a view in the MySQL database that would encapsulate the SQL. Then you would just select * from that view.

Alternatively, you could create a stored procedure, and pass in the names of the columns that you want to be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select fname,sname,contact from table_admin
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake. i want to exclude these fields

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so you will have something like this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    fname,
    lanem
FROM
    tbl_admin
```

You just need to specify what are those and in what order. Instead of using the `*` to fetch all records (columns) in its default order.

**Edit**

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), '<columns_to_omit>,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table>' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database>'), ' FROM <table>');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Actually, I just got it from another's posts so all credits goes to him. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

Comment: sorry, my mistake. i want to exclude these fields

Comment: okay done. found it on some post, but i and many others thinks this is not a good practice though.

Answer (score 0):

**Latest Answer**

ANSWER BY [Mahomedalid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143393/mahomedalid) in [Select all columns except one in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), '<columns_to_omit>,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table>' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database>'), ' FROM <table>');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

For your situation replace the `<columns_to_omit>` with `fname,lname,contact_info`

**Old Answer**

Syntax for retrieving particular column values from table is

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
```

All columns can be retrieved using `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT column_name(s)`

if you are directing your question towards a particular language like **PHP** then the syntax can be like this

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT fname,lname,contact_info FROM tbl_admin");?>
```

Comment: i want to exclude only 3 column, because i have 20+ column and i dont want to select all other fields

Comment: i have more then 30 fields, so i can't type select (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5..... column30)