# How to return columns and joined columns in a certain order (Eloquent)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have the following code:

```
    Incident::where('id','<','35')->with('priority')->paginate(15);
```

Right now this returns the following:
ID, title, description, priority_id and the priority object.

I would like to retrieve only ID, title and the priority object, without description nor priority_id but I want them in a specific order, like this:
ID, priority and title.

But when I do the following:

```
    Incident::where('id','<','5')->with('priority')->paginate(15, array('id', 'priority', 'title'));
```

I get an error saying column incidents.priority not found.

Is there any way to select only the columns I want and in the order I want them when one of them is referenced through a FK?

Thank you!

Comment: It's may be help you.check this link https://packagist.org/packages/witty/laravel-table-view

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612221/how-to-exclude-certains-columns-while-using-eloquent

Comment: i cannot imagine a scenario where it would be a good idea to rely on the order of an array

Comment: @tam sure, it's certainly not the best approach, but sometimes there is not much of a choice...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include `priority` in the list:
`Incident::where('id','<','5')->with('priority')->paginate(15, array('id', 'title'));`

Comment: But then I wouldn't get priority in the place I want it to be :'(

Comment: @SofiaGilardino, can you tell what are you doing with the returned collection?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a callback to the `with` method you can specify the order like so:

```
Incident::where('id','<','35')
    ->with(['priority' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'priority', 'title');
    }])
    ->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not a join.  The `with('priority')` is actually a 2nd separate query that is executed after the `Incident` query and then attached to the `Incident` models.  If you want to reference columns and use a join you would do it like:

```
Incident::select('id', 'priorities.*', 'incidents.title')
    ->leftJoin('priorities', 'priorities.id', '=', 'incidents.priority_id')
    ->where('incidents.id', '>', '5')
    ->paginate(15);
```

If you don't want to use the above then @tam answer would be best but make sure with his solution to include the `id` in the sub query callback because that is how the relation attaches itself to the parent model after the query is ran.