# How to disable or remove updated_At and Created_at when returning data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to remove created_at and updated_at before returning response to api . I want to removie these field from both **Place_Type and Places**
how can I do that? :
I tried : unset(placetypes) but it didn't work

This is my Code:

```
    public function places()
    {

        $placeType = PlaceType::with('places')->where('id', 1)->get();

        return response()->json(['placeType' => $placeType]);
    }
```

The request result:

```
 "placeType": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Moriah O'Conner",
            "icon": "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
            "status": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-12-14 18:23:19",
            "updated_at": "2019-12-14 18:23:19",
            "places": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Linda Leffler",
                    "description": "Alice's shoulder, and it set to work, and very soon came to ME, and told me he was in the air. She did it so VERY remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it would feel very queer to ME.' 'You!' said.",
                    "icon": "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
                    "image_name": "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
                    "rating": 2,
                    "longitude": -53.389979,
                    "latitude": 19.633458,
                    "availability": 1,
                    "status": 1,
                    "place_type_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2019-12-14 18:23:19",
                    "updated_at": "2019-12-14 18:23:19"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Lauren Cartwright",
                    "description": "I should say \"With what porpoise?\"' 'Don't you mean by that?' said the King. 'I can't remember half of anger, and tried to look at it!' This speech caused a remarkable sensation among the leaves.",
                    "icon": "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
                    "image_name": "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
                    "rating": 1,
                    "longitude": -38.117034,
                    "latitude": -32.248637,
                    "availability": 1,
                    "status": 1,
                    "place_type_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2019-12-14 18:23:19",
                    "updated_at": "2019-12-14 18:23:19"
                }...,
               }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different methods you can use.

Method 1 : **Fetch only required fields from the database**

You can use `select()` method for retrieving only required fields from db. Hence you can omit the unnecessary fields.

```
$placeType = PlaceType::with(['places'  => function ($query) {
                    $query->select('id', 'name', 'description', 'icon',
                        'image_name', 'rating', 'longitude', 'latitude',
                        'availability', 'status', 'place_type_id'); //timestamps excluded
                }])
                ->select('id', 'name', 'icon', 'status') //timestamps excluded
                ->where('id', 1)
                ->get();

return response()->json(['placeType' => $placeType]);
```

This code will output only specified fields both in the parent model (`placetype`) and child model (`places`).

If you use these customized select query more than once and writing all field names multiple time is difficult, then you could use model scope like the following.

**PlaceType Model**

```
// add all columns from your table
protected $columns = ['id', 'name', 'icon', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

public function scopeExclude($query,$value=[]) 
{
    return $query->select( array_diff( $this->columns,(array) $value) );
}
```

**Place Model**

```
// add all columns from your table
protected $columns = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'icon', 'image_name',
                        'rating', 'longitude', 'latitude', 'availability',
                        'status', 'place_type_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
                    ];

public function scopeExclude($query,$value=[]) 
{
    return $query->select( array_diff( $this->columns,(array) $value) );
}
```

Then you could remove unwanted fields like  the following

```
$placeType = PlaceType::with(['places' => function ($query) {
                    $query->exclude(['created_at', 'updated_at']); //exclude fields from Place model
                }])
                ->exclude(['created_at', 'updated_at']) //exclude fields from PlaceType model
                ->where('id', 1)
                ->get();
```

Courtesy : [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23612794/6274211) SO answer by @Razor

Method 2 : **Hide your column from serialization where you need**

You can hide your column from serialization using laravel's `makeHidden()` method. In this method after fetching rows with all fields, you are making the specified fields as hidden. [Please note that the excluded variables won't appear on `json` but may visible on dump].

```
//get rows with all fileds (except hidden)
$placeType = PlaceType::with('places')->where('id', 1)->get();
//making timestamps hidden in child model's rows
$placeType->places->makeHidden(['created_at','updated_at']);
//making timestamps hidden in parent model's rows
$placeType->makeHidden(['created_at','updated_at']);

return response()->json($placeType);
```

Courtesy : [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52499101/6274211) SO answer by @sajed

Method 3 : **Using Hidden property**

If the timestamps are unnecessary in most of the time in the app, you could use the model's `hidden` property.

**PlaceType Model** & **Place Model**

```
protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Add the fields to the [`$hidden`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json) array:

```php
// Model

protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

Comment: This must work for any Model query. Please use `protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];` in both `placeType` and `places` model.

Answer (score 2):

1) You just need to declare `public $timestamps = false;` in every model you want to hide it.

2) You can also disable timestamps by removing `$table->timestamps()` from your migration.

3) Declare `protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];` in your model.

Comment: I did that but it still returns updated_at and created_at

Comment: Do it in both model ```Place_Type``` and ```Places``` @Developer

Comment: And if need them but don't want to show them set them in $hidden in your model. ```protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];``` @Developer

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to remove timestamps from model, as mentioned before, place this in your Model:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Also create a migration with following code in the up() method and run it:

```
Schema::table('your_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropTimestamps();
});
```

You can use $table->timestamps() in your down() method to allow rolling back.
or in model

```
const UPDATED_AT = null;
const CREATED_AT = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $placeType is array, you can use this recursive function:

```
function removeTimeStampValues($array) 
{
    if(array_key_exists('created_at', $array) && array_key_exists('updated_at', $array)) {
       unset($array['created_at']);
       unset($array['updated_at']);

    }
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
       if(is_array($value)) {
         $array[$key] = recursiveRemoveTimeStampValue($value);
       }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want these columns, you can do as others said based on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) (under "Timestamps" title).

But if you need these column and just don't want them in the json response, you can use `resource`. See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources).