# Laravel : Get all columns except some of them

Tags: php, laravel

I have a dynamic temp table which columns are `id, name, class, x, y, z`. Columns other than `id, name, class` is always changing. The table could be also `id, name, class, a, b`. The columns other than `id, name, class` contain numerical values that I need to fetch in order to do some calculation with. I need to fetch all fields except `id, name, class`. Is there any way to do it with like `DB::table('tname')->select(*)->except('name','id','class')->get();` or perhaps other way? Also for that dynamic temp table there's no model for it. So solutions with model is required is kind of impossible for me.

Is there any way to select all columns except for some of them with like `DB::table('tname')->select(*)->except('name','id','class')->get();` or perhaps other way?

Comment: If you create the temp table, dont you know what the other columns are called? You had to create them somehow!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude certains columns while using eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612221/how-to-exclude-certains-columns-while-using-eloquent)

Comment: Taking a step back, do you really need to not have these columns? Does your code break if they exist in your dataset, or are you trying to perform some optimization?