# How to do something like SELECT "all columns except .."?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with data in it, called `current`. I import new data into a table called `temp`. Both these tables have auto_increment ID columns.

The table structure is not known in advance for the data import (there are various file structures that I need to import), event though the structure of `current` and `temp` will be the same.

Because of the unknown column configuration of the import files (tables created on the fly for each different file configuration), I cannot select specific columns, hence I would have to select all columns, less the ID column from table `temp` and import the result into table `current`.

I need to import into `temp` first, as the files can be large, and I need to do processing on the data before saving into the database, so I do not want to do any operations on the `current` table before I have imported the separate file first.

The ID column from the `temp` table prevents the insert into the `current` table due to duplicate key.

So I need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `current`
(SELECT **ALL COLUMNS EXCEPT ID** FROM `temp`)
```

Any ideas on how to write the section **ALL COLUMNS EXCEPT ID**? Is this even possible?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `* except foo`. You'll have to list all of the columns, except the ones you don't want.

```
SELECT field1, field2, ..., fieldN ...
```

You could do it via dynamic scripting, e.g. query `information_schema` for the field names, build up the field list as a string, prepare that string as query, execute it, etc...