# MySQL export without primary key?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to export a tablet with a lot of columns (20+). I want to exclude the primary key, but don't want to write SELECT `column2`,`column3` and so on for all the rest columns. I want to export the data without primary key so when I import it, the primary key will be auto incremented. I am using MySql and PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Mmmh, why not just use the `SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table;` function and copy the output of that into your query. So you don't have to type all the columns.

Comment: You can't do this directly with, instead i suggest you export it the normal way then use NotePad++ and regular expressions to remove the primary key column

Answer (score 1):

See this answer found in [select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql):

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), '<columns_to_omit>,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table>' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database>'), ' FROM <table>');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

This helped me a lot on a simmilar problem.