# mysql how to select all and exclude one column from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i have a table name users and i want to download to csv file by a query,
but i dont want to select a password column in table users.

i am new to sql that to fresher, please any one help me.  below is my query

```
function get_all_partnerships_to_download() {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from("$this->_users_table");
        $this->db->join("$this->_user_profile_table",  "$this->_user_profile_table.user_id = $this->_users_table.id");
        $this->db->where("$this->_user_profile_table.participate_as_id", 3);
        $this->db->group_by("$this->_users_table.id");
        $this->db->distinct();

        return $this->db->get($this->_table);

    }
```

Comment: You have to specify column names

Comment: Have a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql

Comment: or create a view without password column and select that view in your php :)

Comment: What is the password column name? and what table is it in

Comment: @M Khalid , no without specifying column names, i thought u asked me to specify in question for your reference

Comment: @qwerty You cant, you cant exclude column names, only specify columns. Post your data structure and someone will write it up for you

Comment: @Matt  column name is password and table name is user_profile