# How to select multiple columns from a table excluding some columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select multiple columns from a table excluding some columns?

I tried:

```
SELECT *!=[column name i want to exclude] from tablename;
```

it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all columns except one in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

Answer (score 7):

```
select column1, column2, column4, column7
from tablename;
```

should be the way to go.

Comment: what if I have to select from a table of say 50 columns and exclude only 5 columns? thank you very much. your help is appreciated.

Comment: there is a solution with metadata. It that is acceptable for you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql

Comment: SELECT *, NULL AS salary FROM users;

this is the solution which came close to my query, in the link you have provided. Thanks.

Comment: is there a way to exclude the column itself