# MYSQL get all rows with only NULL in all columns

Tags: mysql, select, null

I have a table with some rows containing only NULL in all columns except the descrition column.

```
    description | colA | colB
    -------------------------
    Peter       | bla  | NULL
    Frank       | NULL | NULL
    George      | NULL | blub
```

How do I select all rows with NULL in all columns without explicitly naming them?

``` Pseudocode: SELECT ``decription`` WHERE all other columns are NULL ``` should return Frank. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: `SELECT description FROM table_name WHERE colA is NULL and colB IS NULL`

Comment: You can't really refer to "all other columns" in a where clause without naming them individually.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Explicitly naming all other columns will be ugly long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By refering to INFORMATION_SCHEMA and using PREPARE statement, one solution is here, with a full demo provided.

The solution refers to: [Select all columns except one in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

SQL:

```
-- data
create table t1(description char(20), colA char(20), colB char(20));
insert into t1 values
(    'Peter'       , 'bla', NULL),
(    'Frank'       , NULL , NULL),
(    'George'      , NULL , 'blub');
SELECT * FROM t1;

-- Query wanted
SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT description FROM t1 WHERE COALESCE(',
    (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'description,', '') 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = 't1' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'), 
    ') IS NULL');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t1;
+-------------+------+------+
| description | colA | colB |
+-------------+------+------+
| Peter       | bla  | NULL |
| Frank       | NULL | NULL |
| George      | NULL | blub |
+-------------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SET @sql = CONCAT(
    -> 'SELECT description FROM t1 WHERE COALESCE(',
    -> (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'description,', '')
    ->  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    ->  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 't1' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'),
    -> ') IS NULL');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE stmt1;
+-------------+
| description |
+-------------+
| Frank       |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**To elaborate the SET statement before PREPARE:**

1. The SET is to generate a string as below.

   SELECT description FROM t1 WHERE COALESCE( < list of all columns, except `description` > ) IS NULL
2. The  is queried from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, using the method in the reference link.

> To use in your own environment, you need to
>
> 1. Change table name 't1' to your own table name;
> 2. Change TABLE_SCHEMA 'test' to your own database name.

Comment: Thanks, this actually works. Could you elaborate the syntax of your "SET" statement?

Comment: You deserve at least +1 for the serious effort. Please @Fred accept this answer to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT description FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE colA is NULL AND colB is NULL

Comment: "all columns *without explicitly naming them*"