# MySQL - Excluding Rows From SELECT

Tags: mysql, select

I have been given a Table with ~50 columns. Obviously I could select them all with:-

```
SELECT * FROM...
```

However for confidentiality  three columns must not be selected. Many of the columns use long identifiers. Is there a way of selecting all columns by excluding nominated ones rather than selecting all ~47?

Comment: Use views which selects only required fields and in application do select * from view

Comment: duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql