# How can I achieve the following in Codeigniter with except() function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In Codeigniter, you can select all field from a table by simply doing:

`$this->db->select('*')->from('table')->get()->result()`

..and the code above will select all fields from that "`table1`" and  return the result!

Sometimes, you want to select specific fields in that table then you simply:

`$this->db->select('fiels1, field2, field3, field4')->from('table')->get()->result()`

..the above will return result with those specific fields

but sometimes, you want to select all fiedls EXCEPT specific fields and my question is this

How can I achieve this or do something like this

`$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->exept('filed1, field2'); //please note this except()
$this->db->get('table')->result()`

My wish is that I want to select all fields except those that are in the except function to avoid

`$this->db->select('f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14.....');`

I want to do this:

`$this->db->except('f13, f6')->get('table')->result()`

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql

Comment: ^ on top of that, it will probably be easier just to use some array magic to remove the fields you don't want.