# INNER JOIN with ON All columns except one Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, intersect

I have 2 tables(Table1 and Table2). Both tables schema are exactly the same and both might have duplicated set of records except IDs since ID is auto generated.

[image: Table1 and Table2]

I would like to get the common set of records but with ID to follow as Table1's ID. So, I query using Inner join. It works as I expected.

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Param1, Table1.Param2, Table1.Param3
INTO #Common
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Param1 = Table2.Param1
  AND Table1.Param2 = Table2.Param2
  AND Table1.Param3 = Table2.Param3
```

**However, in actual usage, the total number of parameters in both tables will be around 100. So, the total number of comparison inside ON clause will increase up to 100. 
How can I do inner join by excluding one column instead of comparing all columns in ON clause?**

By removing ID column from both tables and doing intersect also no possible since I still want to extract Table1 ID for other purpose. 
I can achieve the common of 2 table by removing ID and compare those 2 table. 
However, that still do not serve my requirement, since I need to get Table1 ID for those common data.

```
SELECT * INTO #TemporaryTable1 FROM Table1
ALTER TABLE #TemporaryTable1 DROP COLUMN ID

SELECT * INTO #TemporaryTable2 FROM Table2
ALTER TABLE #TemporaryTable2 DROP COLUMN ID

SELECT * INTO #Common FROM (SELECT * FROM #TemporaryTable1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM #TemporaryTable2) data
SELECT * FROM #Common
```

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text. Please give a [mcve]. Please read [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover text. Why did the answers from googling your question not solve your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all columns except one in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

Comment: Are all of your params of type `int`? If so, have you considered whether you've picked the right data structure to start with here? A narrow table with `ID, ParamNumber, ParamValue` may be far simpler to work with in the long run.

Comment: Your query looks good but you did not include the output you wanted. It's not too clear.

Comment: Hi Damien, params are not type of int. It will be of nvarchar.

Comment: Hi philipxy, in here, i m trying to get the common parameters set of table 1 and table 2.

Comment: Hi Vijunav, I would like to compare 2 tables. Those 2 tables might have same values for all columns except ID. I want to get the common parameters values among that 2 table but ID to reference back to Table1 ID.

Comment: What is wrong with typing all column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your problem correctly i guess you could generate dynamically the query you want to use using the following code :

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT  ',
    @TBL1 nvarchar(50) = 'data',
    @TBL2 nvarchar(50) = 'data1',
    @EXCLUDEDCOLUMNS nvarchar(100)= 'ID,col1'

-- column selection
SELECT @sql += @tbl1 + '.' + COLUMN_NAME + ' ,
        '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TBL1

-- from clause and remove last ,

set @SQL = LEFT(@sql,LEN(@sql) - 5)


SET @sql += '
FROM ' + @TBL1 + ' INNER JOIN
     ' + @TBL2 + '
  ON '

-- define the on clause
SELECt @SQL  += @tbl1 + '.' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = '+ @tbl2 + '.' + COLUMN_NAME +',
     '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TBL1
  AND COLUMN_NAME not in (@EXCLUDEDCOLUMNS)

--remove last ,

set @SQL = LEFT(@sql,LEN(@sql) - 3)

--SELECt @SQL
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
```

Before you execute make sure the @sql is properly generated. choose the columns you want to exclude from your on clause using the @EXCLUDEDCOLUMNS   parameter.

Comment: Hi Sapi, what if table 1 and table 2 are in separate databases? How does the query be like?

Comment: hey, to select tables in a different database just prefix the table name by [databaseName].[schema].[tableName] ex :  @TBL1 nvarchar(50) = '[prod].dbo.data' .Now if on database is on another server its a bit trickier you will have to create a linked server in sql server but once you do the syntax is identical : [serverName].[dbName].[schemaName].[tableName]