# In a sql query how not to show duplicate columns

Tags: mysql, sql

```
   A(p,q,r,...)
   B(p,l,m,n,...)

   select <columns>
   from A join B on A.p=B.p
```

how do I write  expression where I would like to show

```
A.*
```

But everything in B except p

I don't want to list them by hand:

```
`select A.*, B.l, B.m, B.n, ..`.
```

Because the number of columns in B can be huge. Is there any SQL syntax to achieve this?

Comment: Since `B.p=A.p` does it matter? Note that if you're fetching into an associative array you'll only end up with one `p` value anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select all columns except one in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

For tables

```
A(p,q,r,...)
B(p,l,m,n,...)
```

the query

```
select <columns>
from A join B on A.p=B.p
```

will produce 2 copies of `p` column, whereas

```
select <columns>
from A join B USING(p)
```

and (if possible)

```
select <columns>
from A NATURAL join B
```

will produce one single `p` column.