# Is there a way to SELECT * on a table while also aliasing one column without duplicating the column?

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's say I have a table, `people` with objects such as this:

```
fullName: "John Doe",
id: 1,
isActive: True
```

I could do this to get a table that works for my issue:

```
SELECT p.fullName AS "name",
p.*
FROM people p
```

but this results in two columns with duplicate data, one called `name` and one called `fullName`.

Is there any way to do this without duplicating the columns *and* without listing out each attribute individually? The object I could be potentially working with has over 50 attributes.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do this.

Comment: Some creative, but very ugly, ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql)

Comment: @JNevill I'd dare say this question constituted a duplicate of that one, in fact. Though I'm a little remiss no one high road'd the answer of "refactor and normalize the DB".

Comment: Why not do the renaming in the application that processes the results? This kind of thing is only needed when you're displaying using an automatic reporting tool that depends on the aliases.

Comment: It's poor practice to use `*` here for production queries in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

`SELECT *` should always be avoided except for testing purposes.

If you have a lot of columns and you're too lazy to type in all the columns just create a VIEW, and copy column names from SHOW CREATE VIEW (If you don't need table name and backticks just remove them via search/replace).

```
CREATE VIEW tmp_view AS SELECT * from people;
SHOW CREATE tmp_view;
DROP tmp_view;
```